# Pass an array to a twig macro in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a controller, a twig macro and the main template where the macro is imported. I would like to send an array in my macro and for each row of my table I want to display its data.

A line is composed of : title, description, img, type

**The controller :**

```
/**
 * @Route("/realisations", name="realisations")
 * @Method({"GET"})
 *
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function realisationsAction()
{
    return $this->render('MyBundle:page:realisations.html.twig', $datas = array('type' => 'The type',
                                                                                 'img' => 'test.jpg',
                                                                                 'titre' => 'Test',
                                                                                 'description' => 'The description'));
}
```

**The main template :**

```
{% import "MyBundle:macros:realisationsMacros.html.twig" as macros %}

{{ macros.realisations(datas) }}
```

**The macro :**

```
    {% macro realisations(datas) %}
    {% for data in datas %}
        <div class="project {{ data.type }} isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <div class="content">
                <div class="image">
                    <img src="{{ asset('bundles/jsmetallerie/img/realisations/'~ data.type ~'/13.png') }}" alt="{{ data.titre }}">
                    <div class="item-hover">
                        <ul class="item-icons">
                            <li><a href="{{ asset('bundles/jsmetallerie/img/realisations/'~ data.type ~'/'~ img) }}" data-fancybox><i class="fa fa-search"></i></a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ path('jsm_realisation_projet') }}"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <span class="h6">{{ data.titre }}</span>
                <p>{{ data.description }}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

The Symfony error is : **"Variable "datas" does not exist."**

I think the error comes from creating my table in the controller but I do not know how to create it correctly

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply pass an array with a key named 'datas' as example:

```
    $params = array(
        'datas' => array('type' => 'The type',
                         'img' => 'test.jpg',
                         'titre' => 'Test',
                         'description' => 'The description')
    );

    return $this->render('MyBundle:page:realisations.html.twig', $params);
```

Hope this help